# Why `until` block is designed as it is just a negative version of `while`?

Tags: shell, shell-script

To my understanding, `until` block is just the opposite version of `while`,

like `until "condition A is met"` is equivalent to `while "condition A is not met"`.

In some modern languages such like `python`, there is only `while`.

So why the author of `bourne shell` designed both `until` and `while`?

Is there some situation in which that `while` can't replace `until`?

Answer (score 2):

The Bourne shell, where that syntax come from didn’t have a command negation (`!`) operator. So, while that was not so much an issue for `if` where you could use:

```
if cmd; then
  : no-op
else
  something if cmd returns false
fi
```

That’s more an issue with `while` where, you’d need to do ugly things like:

```
while cmd; [ "$?" -ne 0 ]; do
  ...
done
```

This looks nicer:

```
until cmd; do
  ...
done
```

With `ksh` (and POSIX `sh` that also adopted it (and bash/zsh...)), you can do:

```
if ! cmd; then
  something if cmd fails
fi
while ! cmd; do
  ...
done
```

Though you lose the exact value of the exit status in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Until always runs at least one iteration. Consider case that condition A is met:

```
While A is not met:
run X
```

will not run X. But:

```
do
run X
until A is met
```

will run X once, then evaluate that A is met and continue further on.

Comment: You must be confusing with `C` or `perl`. Shells don't have such statements.